# Transform .HBM model to annotated pojos

Tags: java, hibernate, domain-driven-design, hbm, mda

We have our domain model declared in rusty old hbm files,  we wish to move to POJOs annotated with the javax.persistence.* annotations.

Has anyone had experience doing so?

Are there tools that we could employ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use hbm2java ant task from hibernate-tools.jar. This is a tool known as Hibernate Tool. hbm2java will generate JPA annotated POJOS from hbm files.

See http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/tools/reference/en/html/ant.html

Comment: We tried hbm2java, but it didn't work in our case. So we developed .hbm to .ecore transformation using Epsilon (EMF). It does require some efforts, but it was worth to do.